# How to batch rename files with a random name

Tags: windows, linux, mac, command-line, bash

I have a bunch of photos with varying names.
I want to give each photo a random name<sup>**(*)**</sup>, how do I do that?

<sup>**(*)**</sup><sub>I'm going to put them on a digital photo-frame that can't shuffle</sub>

Comment: Do you want a single solution that works for all of those platforms? Or a solution that works on any one? What script languages are you limited to or prefer? Are all the photos in one folder or multiple?

Comment: @EBGreen - I have a solution that works wherever bash is available. I would also like one that works on windows. (and recommending cygwin is cheating)

Comment: Why not use the MD5 sum?

Comment: While MD5 sums would make name collisions less likely, MD5 collisions are a known issue. http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Comment: @Angel - Using the MD5 sum as a name would have worked pretty well for uniqueness. The extra time to calculate the sum on 4000+ photos would have been a boring wait.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming all the images are in a single folder, this would work in Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | ForEach-Object{Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$(Get-Random)-$($_.Name)"}
```

It is possible that you would get potential name collisions, but Get-Random by default returns a 32 bit unsigned int from 0 to Int32.MaxValue (0 to 2147483647). You could certainly add another Get-Random in to reduce the likelihood of a collision just as in the Bash answer.

Comment: Looks like this appends a second .jpg to the result.

Comment: @useSticks the answer is now edited to remove the duplicate ".jpg"

Answer (score 12):

One way if you have a bash shell handy is to use the `$RANDOM` environment variable. It generates random values between 0 and 32767.

A simple for loop in bash works fine if you only have a few hundred files.

```
for i in *.jpg; do mv -i "$i" ${RANDOM}.jpg; done
```

Since I had about 4000 files to rename I soon got collisions that the `-i` flag to `mv` caught.
Adding another `$RANDOM` took care of that.

```
for i in *.jpg; do mv -i "$i" ${RANDOM}${RANDOM}.jpg; done
```

Comment: Instead of `"${RANDOM}${RANDOM}.jpg"` you could also say `"${RANDOM}-$i"`. This will avoid collisions and keep the old name information (as well as satisfy the random sort requirement).

Comment: Oooh...I like it....I'll tweak the PS solution to incorporate that.

Comment: @bitmask - A good point. In this case the images didn't have any meaningful names and sometimes contained spaces so I was happy to get rid of them.

Comment: how can this be generalized to accept any extension?

Answer (score 4):

`for f in *; do ext=$(echo "$f" | sed 's|\([^.]*\)||'); mv "$f" "$(uuidgen)$ext"; done`

Comment: This does not work properly when the file name is like "myfile.is.a.jpg" the resulting randomm name is like "8c5b4ee8-abd8-4f62-b641-48e58baf9186.is.a.jpg:

Answer (score -1):

Most batch file renamers can do this, [here is one](http://www.nonags.com/freeware-panda-batch-file-renamer_3952.html)

Easy method would be to do a sequential numbering of the file, I am sure there other options with this software, use your imagination.

[Here is the one I use](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/20/bulk-rename-utility-file-renaming-software/) for bulk renaming tasks